# Merge 2 MySQL Database without doubling data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and it contains 4 tables. I am inputting some data there using PHP locally. Then I hired a coder to help me input, we are from different places so I uploaded my PHP scripts and my database in a shared hosting site.

I know that I can also use the site I uploaded for us to have the same database while coding.

Now my problem is I already have a thousand accounts and phpmyadmin loads so slow when I try to check something and edit. So therefor I am coding on my localhost.

Is there a way that I can merge the database of my coder and mine when we are both finished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two MySQL databases of same structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068010/how-to-merge-two-mysql-databases-of-same-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two with double data by exporting one into the other without DROP TABLE arguments, then you can delete columns with something like this.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT id, DISTINCT email FROM table)
```

this will delete all rows that have duplicate email fields.